# How to call a function after a date is selected from a date picker?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I'm quite new to javascript and JSP and am having a difficult time wrapping my head around what's getting called and when and where. I'm writing this all in a single JSP file. The starting code I have right now is:

```
<input type=text name="myTextField" >
<input type=button name="myTextButton" value="Select a date" 
  onclick="displayDatePicker(myTextField)">

<script type="text/javascript">
// ???
</script>
```

The first thing that confuses me is the displayDatePicker function. I can't for the life of me find any documentation on this function (is it jquery? is it javascript? is it bootstrap? can i pass in other args?). An alternative would be to declare a custom function and have myTextButton's onclick call that function. I managed to get that to work, but I don't know how to display a datepicker that actually has a callback when a date is chosen.

Here's the functionality I want to have:

1. User clicks on myTextField, manually types in a date, then an alert
   pops up "You selected ../../...." or "Invalid date selected"
2. User clicks on myTextButton, selects a date from the date picker,
       then myTextField is populated with that date and an alert pops up "You selected ../../...."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will alert values that are typed in the box.  But you should be using a UI for this.  Why reinvent the wheel.  Time is precious.  jQuery UI is among the most popular due to it's cross browser compatibility.

```
<input type="date" id="date">
<button onclick="date()">Select a date</button>

<script>
    function date() {
        var dateVal = document.getElementById("date").value;
        alert("Your typed in " + dateVal);
    }
</script>
```

**jQuery UI Datepicker**

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 4):

Like what others said you can use [Jquery UI datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) for this.
First thing is to import required script and css.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

To answer the functionality that you want. Take a look of example that I created. 
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kencrisjohn/th2o8zyq/)

If user doesn't select in datepicker and manually input text, you should manually check it. 
Here's the example.

```
$( "#myTextField" ).datepicker({
     onClose: function(){
        validate($(this).val());
     }
});

function validate(dateText){
     try {
         alert("You selected is : "+ $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy',dateText));
         } 
     catch (e) {
         alert("invalid date");
      }; 
    }
```

After datepicker is closed validate function will invoke and try to parse, it will return error if date is unparseable.

Answer (score 0):

The `displayDatePicker` is the inbuilt Javascript function written into the JS library which you have used for the DateTime picker.

Also if you are creating your own custom datepicker than you have to include your custom function which will handle the `OnChange`, `Onclick`, `OnSelection` change kind of events.

I would suggest you to use Jquery.UI or Bootstrap control library for datepicker feature.